# Solution for equation $ (1+y)y' + (1-2x)y^2 = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this Bernoulli equation:

\begin{align} (1+y)y' + (1-2x)y^2 = 0 \end{align}

My steps are as follows:

\begin{align} 
  \text{Let } z = y^{1-2} = y^{-1} 
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  z' = (-1)y^{-2}y'
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  y' = \frac{y^{2}}{-1} \cdot z' = -y^2 \cdot z'
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  \therefore (1+y_)(-y^2 \cdot z') + (1-2x)y^2 = 0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  (1 + y)z' = 1 - 2x
\end{align}
\begin{align}
  z' + yz' = 1 -2x
\end{align}

According to the usual routine for solving Bernoulli equations, I should be able to obtain an equation that is linear in $ z $ which I can solve using an integrating factor. Somehow, I am unable to obtain the linear first-order ode. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It is not a Bernoulli equation, because of the $(1+y)$ factor. It is a separable equation, as indicated in MrYouMath's answer.

Comment: Oh. I see. I got misled by the $ y^2 $ term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$(1+y)y'=-(1-2x)y^2 \implies (1+y)/y^2dy=-(1-2x)dx,$$ which is separable.